# can anybody tell me the error with prim function?

Tags: c++11

There is a problem with the prim function.
A segmentation fault I guess.
Please help me with this. I have tried a lot now.
s is the starting vertex which actually doesn't matter.
arr is a 2D array that stores weights.
V is a 2D array that stores adjacent edges.
check array stores min distances.
visit stores visited nodes.

```
#define INF 99999;
typedef long int ull;
bool visit[3000]={false};
vector<ull>check(3000,0);

void prim(ull in,vector<ull>V[],ull **arr)
{
ull i;
visit[in]=true;


for(i=0;i<V[in].size();i++)
{
    if(!visit[V[in][i]])
    {
        check[V[in][i]]=min(check[V[in][i]],arr[in][V[in][i]]);
    }

}
check[in]=INF;
}

void solve()
{
ull i,j,n,e,s,u,v,w;
cin>>n>>e;
vector<ull>V[n];
ull **arr=new ull*[n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    arr[i]=new ull[n];
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    check[i]=INF;
}

for(i=0;i<e;i++)
{
    cin>>u>>v>>w;
    u--;
    v--;
    arr[u][v]=w;
    arr[v][u]=w;
    V[u].push_back(v);
    V[v].push_back(u);
}
cin>>s;
s--;
ull ind,ad=0;
check[s]=0;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   auto it=min_element(check.begin(),check.end());
   ad+=check[it-check.begin()];


   ind=(it-check.begin());

  prim(ind,V,arr);

}

cout<<ad<<"\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a long int as an index for a static array. Your vector is of type ull which is then being used as an index for the bool array visit.

Your options are to either dynamically allocate your visit array, or to change the datatype of your vector.